# PHP session alternative, shared by everybody

Tags: php, session

All the visitors on our site needs to be able to access data from a slightly advanced data structure.

Currently we have the data structure in a session variable, but as far as I understand session means that all of our visitors have their own copy of the data.

That is not good as we get more and more visitors all the time.

So is there an alternative to session that we can use? An alternative that is shared by all the users.

Comment: Have you tried a database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for a database. However I feel like you're looking for something more temporary than a full database, more something to represent the current state of your app/site? If I'm right in this, a cache of some kind should suit your needs. Try [memcached](http://memcached.org/) or [Redis](http://redis.io/).

Comment: You just copied another users comment. I'm not going to down-vote you..but common man.

Comment: If you're talking about the database comment, I was in the process of writing my response when the comment was posted. As well, the main bulk of my answer was that that's what it sounds like, however his needs seem more like a cache than a full database. I do not see any comments relating to using a cache, or suggestions on his/her options on that front.

Comment: Sounds like a great idea. Any recommendations on whether I should choose memcached or Redis?

Comment: There's alot of debate about that, but honestly they should both suit your needs just fine. If you want to read more about it, a quick google should yield a bunch of articles comparing the two. There seem to be two official Memcached extensions on the PHP site, or for Redis a quick google found an extension available on github. It's really up to you.